# Make a new branch from master then revert master back to certain commit

Tags: git

I would like to make a branch from master then revert master back to a certain point. How can this be achieved with git?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`git checkout master`
`git branch newBranch`
`git reset shaToResetMasterTo`

Comment: Now the remote repo is ahead by many commits. How can I push my reverted changes back? Is there a way to revert by range? like `git revert HEAD^..shaResettedTo`

Comment: Not sure I am following you.  Do you want both the `newBranch` and master to be at the same spot?

Comment: No, I want something like `git reset shaHere` to make a commit to undo all the previous changes so master isn't behind on remote/master. Make sense? Something like `git revert <sha>` but that reverts one commit.

Comment: Ahh, I misread your comment. `git push remote master` if it is tracking the remote master, it will push remote/master to the correct spot.

Comment: You should change last line to `git reset --hard shaToResetMasterTo`.

Comment: Comment by prakharsingh95 is vital, if you don't do this, changes after shaToResetMasterTo remain as local changes. This will revert those changes. Though any files created after the sha will still be there even with this.